# how to fix "Cannot read property 'options' of null" in this code?

Tags: reactjs

I want to add the user to the options array which I have defined inside the state. Problem is whenever I use `prevstate.options.concat([username])`. it shows this error. While when I just push username using `this.state.push(username)` to the array no error occurs. But for good practice in React we never alter directly the state variable, that's why I was using `prevstate` so I want to know why I am getting this error.

As I am getting value of user and `this.state.options` also showing in the console when I declare inside `adduser`so I want to know why my setState is not working using `prevstate` variable?

```
class Login extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.addUser = this.addUser.bind(this)
        this.State = {
            options : ['hello']
        }
    }

    addUser(username){
        console.log(username)
        console.log(this.State.options)
        this.State.options.push(username)

        this.setState((prevState)=>{
            // console.log(prevState.options)
            return {
                options : prevState.options.concat([username])
            }
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Form addUser = {this.addUser}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}



class Form extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.formData = this.formData.bind(this);
    }
    formData(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const username = e.target.elements.user.value.trim();
        console.log(username);
        this.props.addUser(username);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.formData}>
                    Name: <input type="text" name="user"></input>
                        <input type ="submit"></input>
                </form>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Login /> , document.getElementById('app'));
```

actual result would be to concat a user in the options array using setState

Comment: `this.State` => `this.state` in your `contructor()`

Comment: nothing happened

Comment: Can you also do the same on line `12/13` as you have `this.State.options` not `this.state.options`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I have mocked your component in a `sandBox` and the following seems to be working. Here is the `sandBox`: https://codesandbox.io/s/mq3qyvvjkx

You're issue seems to have been using `this.State` instead of `this.state` (lower case `s`) multiple times in your component. And this looks why you were receiving your error.

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addUser = this.addUser.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      options: ["hello"]
    };
  }

  addUser(username) {
    console.log(username);
    console.log(this.state.options);
    this.state.options.push(username);

    this.setState(prevState => {
      // console.log(prevState.options)
      return {
        options: prevState.options.concat([username])
      };
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form addUser={this.addUser} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.formData = this.formData.bind(this);
  }
  formData(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const username = e.target.elements.user.value.trim();
    console.log(username);
    this.props.addUser(username);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.formData}>
          Name: <input type="text" name="user" />
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The following produces the following console outputs, with no console errors.

```
Corbuk
Corbuk
["hello", "corbuk"]
```

Please let me know if this is the expected output?

Comment: Thank you very much i ddn notice that thing . :)